# Test integration .Net Core with TestServer return 404 not found?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing, httpclient

I'm trying to create a Integration Test project , for test my web api .Net Core with the Microsoft sample best practice here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing
But i don't know why, i always get a error message [404 not found], the HttpClient can't find the 'testServer' . And i'm sure my 'route' is right ["api/Registration/" + guid] , if i try on debug mode from iisexpress. it's work great

If someone have some idea to fix it, will be very gratefull. Thanks

Here is the code i use in my Integration Test project:

**RegistrationIntegrationTest.cs:**

```
[TestClass]
public class RegistrationIntegrationTest
{
    private static TestServer server;
    private static HttpClient client;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var projectPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(basePath, "../../../../Registration"));

        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(projectPath)
            .UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

        server = new TestServer(builder);
        client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetRegistrationResponse(string guid)
    {
        var request = "api/Registration/" + guid;

        var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetRegistration()
    {
        // Act
        var responseString = await GetRegistrationResponse("A5A3CBFD-8B61-E711-80E2-00505693113A");
        // Assert
        Assert.Equals("test",
            responseString);
    }
}
```

And here is my startup Class from my Integration Test project:

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddAntiforgery();
        services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(this.Container));
        services.Configure<MyAppSettings>(Configuration);
        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(this.Container);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        }
        else if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://apitest.swisscaution.ch"));
        }
        else if (env.IsProduction())
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://internalapi.swisscaution.ch"));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad application environement.");
        }

        app.UseMvc();

        this.InitializeContainer(app);
    }
```

Here is a photo of the architecture of my solution Visual Studio,
as you can see, the integration test project is separate from my web api project called 'registration'
[image]

The Exception i get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  find finally the problem.
Is because my [ Integration Test Project ] was target the .Net Core Version , and i tried to test and host a project with .Net Framework 4.5.6 Version.
I find the solution online, i need to modify the csproj file and add this 3 config on the "PropertyGroup" section.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the url i find : http://quabr.com/44027215/system-net-http-httpclient-microsoft-aspnetcore-testhost-testserver-createclient